# set "input" as default style for newline entry

Tags: stylesheet

I altered the notebook stylesheet **ArticleJournal** to my needs and I'm using it as a private stylesheet. However, every time a new line is encountered; it assumes as **text** by default since its a journal article and it makes sense. How can I change it to "**input**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Option Inspector to change the DefaultNewCellStyle to Input in your stylesheet notebook.

[image: inspector]

Comment: This worked for current open notebook, I tried to Format-> Edit Stylesheet and change the cell options inside it; How can I apply it to the stylesheet so that it's scope is global when ever I use this stylesheet.

Comment: Open the stylesheet as a notebook, make this change in that notebook. and save it as a stylesheet. Any new notebook created in changed style should have the new behavior.

Comment: It does not work.  New cells **only in the style sheet** are input cells, which is useless.

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE.  After you made the change in the style sheet notebook did you save it so that it replaced the previous version? Did you quit Mathematica and start a new session with a fresh notebook and apply the saved style sheet to it?

Comment: I have restarted Mathematica, installed the style sheet and it works very well with new files, except for this particular option `DefaultNewCellStyle`.  I am sure the option has been set in the style sheet since it is effective therein.  Only inheritance of this option is broken.

Comment: I have tried with the option CellFrame: same problem: it works obviously in the style but it is not inherited.

Comment: I have tried with the style sheet StandardReport.  I can make a custom style with different grey level for input cells, I can set `DefaultNewCellStyle` to Text  (instead of default Input) in custom style sheet but the notebook does not inherit the feature.  Style change does not require saving the style sheet nor restarting Mathematica,

Comment: Installing the style sheet, restarting Mathematica and trying with a new fille does not help.

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE. Than I am sorry but I have no idea what is going wrong.