# How can I change the default cell type in Mathematica from Input to Code?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

Every time I type something into a notebook, I am compelled to first change the cell type from `Input` to `Code`, and then unset the menu option in `Cell > Cell Properties > Initialization Cell`.

What global notebook option must I edit to have a non-initialised `Code` cell created by default when I enter text into a notebook? The following link did not help me very much:

[How do I change the default format type of new cells?](https://support.wolfram.com/34575)

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**

I have tried changing the option in Option Inspector, but the change does not get saved:

[image]

**Edit 2**

I am leaving Edit 1 unaltered, so that Domen's remark has context.

[image]

Comment: What is the reason to change it in the first place?

Comment: It is noted in the first paragraph. I have very little need for the `Input` cell, since I prefer the formatting of `Code`.

Comment: Take a look at `DefaultNewCellStyle`: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92017/set-input-as-default-style-for-newline-entry/92025#92025

Comment: That is the suggestion in the link in my post. I tried changing "Input" to "Code" there, but the option cannot be saved. Clicking Apply does not do anything.

Comment: No it is not, the option name is different.

Comment: It is. Please see my edit above.

Comment: Please read the tutorial you provided _carefully_. The second bullet point states you should select **Global Preferences** in the first drop-down, yet you have selected **Selection**.

Comment: @Domen please see above. The first image was actually posted in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your [initialization file](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html):

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
    DefaultNewCellStyle -> "Code",  
    InitializationCellEvaluation -> False]
```

(but see [note](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InitializationCellEvaluation.html) about `InitializationCellEvaluation`).

This is slightly different from what you are asking if you want to mark just some cells for initialization (the above solution turns it off globally). Unfortunately, I don't know how to avoid that.